# What is the meaning of "exploitation" in a publicity agreement and is it necessary for a waiver of claims?

Tags: copyright, contract-law, new-york-state, right-of-publicity

An agreement says:

> "I hereby expressly release, discharge and waive all claims, demands, losses and liabilities...which may arise from my participation...hereunder or as a result of the exploitation of the rights granted hereunder."

What is exactly is meant by "exploitation" here?

Seems like "*as a result of the utilization of the rights granted hereunder*" would have the same meaning and reach the same goal (waiver of claims).

Not sure if this is a term of art, so to speak, though and if it's not used then the meaning of the provision would change (lessen the company's protection).

Comment: What jurisdiction is this for?

Comment: The jurisdiction is New York

Answer (score 1):

"Utilization of" and "exploitation of" mean the same thing in this context.